# The following location is not accessible, because it is in a different site collection: [infoPathFilePath].xsn

Tags: 2010, infopath, sharepoint-server

I am using sharepoint 2010. We have webApplicationA. On this webapplication I have stored a infopath form in the FormServerTemplates library. This is the url of this xsn file:

```
http://WebApplicationA.lan/FormServerTemplates/myInfoPathFormV53.xsn
```

On webApplicationB I have instances of this infopath form. This is the url of one of the items:

```
http://WebApplicationB.lan/safety/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/safety/Ongevallen%20registratie/OngevalMelding%20-%202012-07-04T13_34_59.xml&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frecordcenter%2Erai%2Elan%2Fsafety%2FOngevallen%2520registratie%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1&ClientInstalled=false&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frecordcenter%2Erai%2Elan%2Fsafety%2FOngevallen%2520registratie%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

When I try to open them I got this error:

> The following location is not accessible, because it is in a different
>   site collection:
>   `http://WebApplicationA.lan/FormServerTemplates/Ongevallen%20Formulier%20V53.xsn`.
>   Click Try Again to attempt to load the form again. If this error
>   persists, contact the support team for the Web site.
>
> Click Close to exit this message.
>
> Show error details

In the uls I found this error:

> MetaInformationByUrl:CrossSite check failed for site

In the central admin I have enabled the infopath option "Cross-Domain Access for User Form Templates".

Why do I got this error? Is it not possible to reach the xsn file in another web application in the same farm?

**UPDATE:**

When I go to the webApplicationA where the items are comming from. And go to the content type settings I see this template path: `/FormServerTemplates/Ongevallen Formulier V55.xsn`

So there is a difference in versions. How can I fix this?

Comment: are you using the web based form?

Comment: yes it is a webbased form.

Comment: maybe this helps, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/372790ac-6925-41a3-9346-8aecb002cb5f/webenabled-infopath-form-there-has-been-an-error-while-loading-the-form?forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs only when you are using InfoPath 2007. With InfoPath 2010 it is working fine. Maybe because the infopath form is created by InfoPath 2010.

Comment: Hi, Plz accept your own answer as answer, so that above question will be get removed from unanswered questions list